# jsf 2 and oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, hibernate-mapping

i am using jsf2 hibernate 4.1.4 and spring3 in my project. but in my defaut.xhtml i can only insert data to oracle. but i cannot see the data in my page. add new customer is done. but data table code in my jsf cannot run. 
my error is:

```
value="#{CustomerMB.getCustomerList()}":org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CUSTOMER is not mapped [from CUSTOMER]
```

default.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>



        <h:dataTable value="#{CustomerMB.getCustomerList()}" var="c"
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            >

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Customer ID
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.customerId}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.name}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Address
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.address}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Created Date
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.createdDate}
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

        <h2>Add New Customer</h2>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                Customer ID : 
                <h:inputText id="customerId" value="#{CustomerMB.customerId}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="customerId" >
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="customerId" style="color:red" />
                Name : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{CustomerMB.name}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />

                Address : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{CustomerMB.address}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>

                <h:message for="address" style="color:red" />

created Date : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="createdDate" value="#{CustomerMB.createdDate}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="createdDate" >
                </h:inputTextarea>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}" />

        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Customermanagedbean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="CustomerMB")
@RequestScoped
public class Customermanagedbean implements Serializable{
@ManagedProperty(value="#{CustomerBoImpl}")
ICustomerBo customerBoImpl;
List<Customer> CustomerList;
public int customerId;
public String name;
public String address;
public String createdDate;



public ICustomerBo getCustomerBoImpl() {
    return customerBoImpl;
}
public void setCustomerBoImpl(ICustomerBo customerBoImpl) {
    this.customerBoImpl = customerBoImpl;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    CustomerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    CustomerList.addAll(getCustomerBoImpl().findAllCustomer());

    return CustomerList;
}



public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    CustomerList = customerList;
}
public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
//add a new customer data into database
public String addCustomer(){

    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setCustomerId(getCustomerId());
    cust.setName(getName());
    cust.setAddress(getAddress());
cust.setCreatedDate(getCreatedDate());

    getCustomerBoImpl().addCustomer(cust);


    clearForm();

    return "";
}

//clear form values
private void clearForm(){
        setName("");
    setAddress("");
    setCreatedDate("");
}


}
```

CustomerBoImpl.java

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomerBoImpl implements ICustomerBo{

    ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl;



    public ICustomerDao getCustomerDaoImpl() {
        return customerDaoImpl;
    }

    public void setCustomerDaoImpl(ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl) {
        this.customerDaoImpl = customerDaoImpl;
    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        getCustomerDaoImpl().addCustomer(customer);

    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().updateCustomer(customer);
    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().deleteCustomer(customer);
    }

@Override
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return getCustomerDaoImpl().findAllCustomer();
    }
}
```

what is wrong?
[image]

customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")

public class Customer{

    public int customerId;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String createdDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }



}
```

CustomerDaoImpl.java

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements ICustomerDao{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;}
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(customer);

    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(customer);
    }


    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){
        sessionFactory.openSession();

        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession

().createQuery("from CUSTOMER").list();
        return list;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the list from getCustomerList() is actually filled with data?

Comment: Just put a log statement of the list.

Comment: @ftom2, now i have this error:CUSTOMER is not mapped [from CUSTOMER]. i use innotation in my customer class. i add it above.

Comment: @sami It's case sensitive so probably It does not map to CUSTOMER but to Customer

Comment: I think it is not an issue but usually I map a value like a bean property <h:dataTable value="#{CustomerMB.customerList}"/> instead of <h:dataTable value="#{CustomerMB.getCustomerList()}"/>. BTW component datatable can invoke method getCustomerList several times, so better to move all "database" logic to the constructor.

Comment: when i put CustomerMB.customerList instead, i have error:/default.xhtml @20,8 value="#{CustomerMB.CustomerList}": Property 'CustomerList' not found on type managedbean.Customermanagedbean

Comment: sounds like you need to open a new question...

Comment: You have "Property 'CustomerList' not found" because your property name is "customerList" (starts from low case 'c')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in my CustomerDaoImpl.java.
In the HQL , you should use the java class name and property name of the mapped @Entity instead of the actual table name and column name , so the HQL should be :

```
List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Customer").list();
        return list;
```